# Can a B1/B2 visa be renewed within the United States?

Tags: visas, usa, visa-renewals

My family goes to the United States every year for Christmas. This year the visa B1/B2 expires. Is it possible to renew our visas when we are within the United States, instead of renewing it in the country we applied from?

Note: I am not asking for visa extension.

Comment: What's your purpose in applying for the visa in the US?  As noted in the answers, it's not necessary for your visa to be valid beyond the date of arrival. So you have nearly an entire year from the end of the last trip before the visa expires to the beginning of the first trip after it expires during which you can apply for a new visa at home. Does that solve your problem

Answer (score 4):

No. You cannot receive a US visa from inside the United States (there are some exceptions for diplomats and foreign government officials, but those are special cases).

[You don't have to apply for a visa in your country of origin](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62016/can-i-indian-citizen-apply-for-b1-b2-us-visa-while-i-am-on-a-visitor-visa-in) (you'd generally apply wherever you are resident), but there may be a higher risk of refusal if you apply away from your home in some cases.

[US visas only need to be valid on the date of entry](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-expiration-date.html), so you could still use yours for this trip even if the visas will expire during the time you are in the US.

Comment: "Some exceptions": the applicant must be posted to the US and getting an A or G visa (maybe also NATO; I don't remember).  So the Chinese ambassador to Canada won't be able to get a B visa while in the US as I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Visas aren't issued inside the US, but on the other hand, the visa expiry date does nothing to your status in the US. Rather, it is by the date stated on the entry stamp in your passport that you must leave.

In fact, you can undertake trips of max 30 days to Canada or Mexico and then re-enter the US, in case you're within the period of stay granted on entry but having an expired visa.

However, for your 2019 visit you'll need to obtain a new visa, which can only be done at a US embassy/consulate.