# If I am Australian, can I apply for a new US visa replacement from London? Or does it need to be my home country?

Tags: visas, usa, australian-citizens, lost-documents

I lost my passport in the US, and it has my O1 visa in it. I was supposed to go to London. Can I replace my US visa from London or do I have to go back to Australia?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I ( Indian citizen) apply for B1/B2 US Visa while I am on a visitor visa in Melbourne, Australia](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62016/can-i-indian-citizen-apply-for-b1-b2-us-visa-while-i-am-on-a-visitor-visa-in)

Comment: Questions about work visas should be asked on our sister site [expatriates.se].

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn New visa applications are often treated differently to replacements.

Comment: @MichaelHampton This question is about replacing the visa while travelling (within scope), not work itself.

Comment: @jpatokal Sure, but it's a question that's fundamentally about the work visa. The folks at Expatriates have expertise on this, whereas we usually don't.

Answer (score 1):

The US generally prefers that applicants apply in their place of residence, but in most cases this is just a preference. Consular staff in an applicant's place of residence are in a better position to judge the applicant's circumstances.  To replace a lost or stolen visa, or even an expired visa for someone who resides in the US, any convenient US consulate will do.